# Apache SOLR index on remote server

Tags: solr

I want to be able to run a SOLR instance on my local computer by have the index directory on a remote server. Is this possible ?

I've been trying to look for a solution for days. Please help.

**Update:** We've got a business legal requirement where we are not allowed store client data on our servers ... we can just read, insert, delete and update it on Client request via our website and the data has to be stored on client servers. So each client will have their own index and we cannot run SOLR or any other web application on Client's server. Some of the clients have dropbox business account. So we thought may be just having the SOLR index file upload to dropbox might work.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The solr indexes are just files, so you could potentially mount the index directory with NFS or something, but it'll likely cause problems. Just install and index locally.

Comment: We've got a business legal requirement where we are not allowed store client data on our servers ... we can just read, insert, delete and update it on Client request via our website and the data has to be stored on client servers. So each client will have their own index.

Comment: Install solr on each client server, in that case. There's not a good reason to split up the indexes and Solr installation.

Comment: We are not allowed to do that either. Some of our clients have dropbox business accounts and we can't install SOLR on dropbox so just having SOLR index files on dropbox was an idea.

Comment: It doesn't sound like your legal requirements are up-to-date with the technical reality. Putting your solr index files on Dropbox(!?!) is almost certainly The Wrong Way To Do It™ and will cause no end of pain for you. Either your clients are going to need a *real server* where they host their own solr installation or you're going to need to be able to store client indexes on a machine you control.

Answer (score 0):

enable remote streaming in solrConfig.xml and configure the remote file location in it.

It's working